# How to iterate over the columns of a Dataset?

Tags: dataset, iterators

I have a `Dataset` with a simple structure, like this:

```
Dataset[{
 <|"X" -> 0.,  "N" ->  14, "S" -> 106.85, "M0" -> 8962.85, "M1" -> 129.71|>, 
 <|"X" -> 0.5, "N" ->  14, "S" -> 104.81, "M0" -> 8956.78, "M1" -> 135.78|>, 
 <|"X" -> 1.,  "N" -> 434, "S" -> 43.89,  "M0" ->  239.46, "M1" ->  53.84|>, 
 <|"X" -> 1.5, "N" -> 529, "S" -> 49.97,  "M0" ->  168.72, "M1" ->  71.90|>, 
 <|"X" -> 2.,  "N" -> 578, "S" -> 52.61,  "M0" ->  139.30, "M1" ->  80.93|>
}]
```

(The actual dataset has around 20 columns, and about 7K rows.)

Does *Mathematica* have a built-in way to iterate over the columns of such a dataset?

(I'm looking for something analogous to the `Keys` method for `Association`s.)

Ultimately what I want to do is this: for each column `Y` other than `X`, extract the list of pairs that one would get from transposing the pair of columns `{X, Y}`, so that I can pass it to `ListPlot`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here an approach that uses some `Dataset` related functionality. Doesn't look too readable to me, but in its core it uses the column names to access the data-set and things like `Keys` and `Values`. Everything can be found in the documentation of `Dataset`:

```
 d = Dataset[{<|"X" -> 0., "N" -> 14, "S" -> 106.85, "M0" -> 8962.85, 
    "M1" -> 129.71|>, <|"X" -> 0.5, "N" -> 14, "S" -> 104.81, 
    "M0" -> 8956.78, "M1" -> 135.78|>, <|"X" -> 1., "N" -> 434, 
    "S" -> 43.89, "M0" -> 239.46, "M1" -> 53.84|>, <|"X" -> 1.5, 
    "N" -> 529, "S" -> 49.97, "M0" -> 168.72, "M1" -> 71.90|>, <|
    "X" -> 2., "N" -> 578, "S" -> 52.61, "M0" -> 139.30, 
    "M1" -> 80.93|>}];
```

First create the list of column pairs we want:

```
tup = Tuples[{{First[#]}, Rest[#]}] &[Normal[d[[1, Keys]]]]
(* {{"X", "N"}, {"X", "S"}, {"X", "M0"}, {"X", "M1"}} *)
```

Then you can plot it by extracting the values:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Normal[d[[All, #]][Values]] & /@ tup
 , PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

To get the data arranged for use in `ListPlot`, you'll have to use `'Normal` - e.g. like this:

```
data = Transpose[Normal[Map[Values,
     Dataset[{<|"X" -> 0., "N" -> 14, "S" -> 106.85, "M0" -> 8962.85, 
        "M1" -> 129.71|>, <|"X" -> 0.5, "N" -> 14, "S" -> 104.81, 
        "M0" -> 8956.78, "M1" -> 135.78|>, <|"X" -> 1., "N" -> 434, 
        "S" -> 43.89, "M0" -> 239.46, "M1" -> 53.84|>, <|"X" -> 1.5, 
        "N" -> 529, "S" -> 49.97, "M0" -> 168.72, "M1" -> 71.90|>, <|
        "X" -> 2., "N" -> 578, "S" -> 52.61, "M0" -> 139.30, 
        "M1" -> 80.93|>}]
     ]]];

ListLinePlot[Map[Transpose[{data[[1]], #}] &, Rest[data]], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: listlineplot]

By using `Transpose` on the array of values, I get the `"X"` entries as the first row. This allows me to combine this row with all other rows, one at a time, in `ListLinePlot`. To get the plot, the `Transpose` has to be undone by another `Transpose`.

This approach works for the `DataSet` in your question because is has the structure of a full array that can be transposed, i.e., the keys in each `Association` are the same.

Answer (score 5):

I'll present an answer that doesn't require us to first convert the whole `Dataset` via `Normal` and then applying `ListLinePlot`. Instead, we collect the `Keys` and use the `Dataset` query approach.

```
(* Here ds is the Dataset *)

keys = Normal@Keys[ds][1]; (* The Column names of the Dataset *)
{first, rest} = {First@keys, Rest@keys}; (* separating the columns of interest *)
cn = Evaluate@ToExpression[{"#" ~~ first, "#" ~~ #} & /@ rest] &;
ds[ListLinePlot[Transpose[##], PlotRange -> All] &, cn]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This is another alternative using Column indexes rather than Keys.

```
Table[Values[Normal[data[All, {1, i}]]], {i, 2, Length[data[1]]}] // ListLinePlot
```

I cant help thinking it should be easier than this though.   `ListLinePlot` accepts lists of associations it should really accept lists of datasets too.  It also accepts the Key of a dataset as the x value so it should be possible to form an approach based on that too, by making column X values the keys for Value N, S etc.

Comment: In retrospect I seem to arrived independently at a close relative of @Halirutan 's answer.  Happy to delete :)

Comment: No, leave it. I don't think my answer looks especially beautiful and the more different ways (even if the differ only a bit) we have, the better.

Comment: Thanks!  But note: `... {..., Length[data]}...` is not right.  With a more complete implementation of datasets, it would be `Width[data]`, but here we may have to settle for `Length[data[1]]`, or some such.

Comment: Good point.  Fooled by a symmetrical dataset.  Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a utility, `associationOuter` that takes lists of `Associations` as inputs (as opposed to `Outer` which works on sequences). User passes functions to apply to `Keys` and `Values` separately:

```
associationOuter[{f_, fOpts__}, {g_, gOpts__}][as_List] := 
  Module[{keyout, valout},
   keyout =   as // Map[Keys] /* (Outer[f, Sequence @@ #, fOpts] &) ;
   valout = as // Map[Values] /* (Outer[g, Sequence @@ #, gOpts] &);
   {keyout, valout} // Transpose // 
      Map[Transpose /* Map[Apply[Rule]]] // Flatten // Association
   ]
```

Then, given:

`ds[All , {{"X"}, Rest} ]`

[image]

The plots can be obtained separately (shown below) or combined by moving `ListPlot` a level up in the query.

```
ds[All , {{"X"}, Rest} /* associationOuter[{List, 1}, {List, 1}]][
   Transpose][All, ListPlot[#, Joined -> True] &] // Normal
```

[image]